# What is slew rate control for an input GPIO?

Tags: gpio

I see a register where you can make the slew rate fast or slow for the GPIO. Does this matter when GPIO is configured as an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this matter when GPIO is configured as an input?

No. The slew rate is the rate of change of the *output* voltage. This setting makes no difference for an input pin.